# How to import get response times interceptor to Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, interceptor

All my imported interceptors work fine in Axios, but getResponseTime interceptor doesn't.

`NON WORKING EXAMPLE`

What about just to assume the case I want to manage and import interceptors to Axios. I'd like to define them in separate file `logTimeInterceptor.js`:

```js
export const responseTimeInterceptor = (response) => {
  // to avoid overwriting if another interceptor
  // already defined the same object (meta)
  response.meta = response.meta || {}
  response.meta.requestStartedAt = new Date().getTime()
  return response
}


export const logResponseTimeInterceptor = ((response) => {
    // Logs response time - only for successful requests
    console.log(
      ` API | Execution time for: ${response.config.url} - ${
        new Date().getTime() - response.config.meta.requestStartedAt
      } ms`
    )
    return response
  },
  // Support for failed requests
  // Handle 4xx & 5xx responses
  (response) => {
    console.error(
      ` API | Execution time for: ${response.config.url} - ${
        new Date().getTime() - response.config.meta.requestStartedAt
      } ms`
    )
    throw response
  }
)
```

Then I import them and I use them in the way in a given example of `httpClient.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { ApiSettings } from '@/api/config'
import {
  responseTimeInterceptor,
  logResponseTimeInterceptor
} from '@/api/interceptors/logTimeInterceptor'

// ==============    A P I   C L I E N T    =============
const httpClient = axios.create(ApiSettings)

// ============== A P I   I N T E R C E P T O R S =============
httpClient.interceptors.request.use(authInterceptor)
httpClient.interceptors.response.use(
  responseTimeInterceptor,
  logResponseTimeInterceptor,
)

export default httpClient
```

But those interceptors don't work as imports together, and I think they has to stay intact in httpClient file. Please advise. It only breaks with logResponseTimes interceptor, the others work fine.

// UPDATE: According to @IVO GELOV I tried with one argument but still with no success, also I moved `responseTimeInterceptor` to request, the refactored code looks as follows:

```
// httpClient.js
httpClient.interceptors.request.use(responseTimeInterceptor)
httpClient.interceptors.response.use(logResponseTimeInterceptor)
httpClient.interceptors.response.use(logResponseErrorTimeInterceptor)
```

responseTimeInterceptor.js

```
export const responseTimeInterceptor = (response) => {
  // to avoid overwriting if another interceptor
  // already defined the same object (meta)
  response.meta = response.meta || {}
  response.meta.requestStartedAt = new Date().getTime()
  return response
}

export const logResponseTimeInterceptor = (response) => {
  // Logs response time - only for successful requests
  console.log(
    ` API | Execution time for: ${response.config.url} - ${
      new Date().getTime() - response.config.meta.requestStartedAt
    } ms`
  )
  return response
}

export const logResponseErrorTimeInterceptor = (response) => {
  // Support for failed requests
  // Handle 4xx & 5xx responses
  console.error(
    ` API | Execution time for: ${response.config.url} - ${
      new Date().getTime() - response.config.meta.requestStartedAt
    } ms`
  )
  throw response
}
```

Comment: I believe that you should initialize the timer inside the **request** interceptor and then stop it inside the **response** interceptor. You don't need a **third** interceptor. Also, I think that the `use()` method only accepts a single argument - not 2 like in your code.

Comment: @IVOGELOV According to your answer I updated the question with refactored code but doesn't work as it meant to.

Comment: Keep in mind that response interceptors are called in reverse order. If the last one throws or returns a Promise rejection - previous interceptors will not be called.